# Two calls to s3_uploader_form on same view not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

My question is about using the s3_direct_upload gem.  I'm attempting to put two upload buttons on the view (s3_uploader_form methods) at the same time.  No matter how I structure it, only the first instance works, the second will change the text after the button (from 'no file chosen' to the name of the file) but will not cause any attempt at upload. I know it's not the controllers, because individually, the calls work.  It's only when both are on the view at the same time.

Below is the relevant view code

```
<table>

    <tr> <th>File</th> <th>license</th></tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: company_program_version_license_index_path(@company, @program, @license),
              id: "s3_uploader",
              callback_param: "programfile[direct_upload_url]",
              expiration: 24.hours.from_now.utc.iso8601,
              max_file_size: 2000.megabytes do %>
            <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: false %>
            <% end %>       
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: company_program_version_license_index_path(@company, @program, @license),
              id: "s3_uploader",
              callback_param: "license[direct_upload_url]",
              expiration: 24.hours.from_now.utc.iso8601,
              max_file_size: 2000.megabytes do %>
              <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: false %>
            <% end %>       
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I've reversed the order and removed the calls from the table, but always, only the first one encountered on the view works.  The 2nd will only change the text after the button with no other effect.

Answer (score 0):

From the project's [README](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload):

> > A unique :id should be added to file_field_tag if there is many 's3_uploader_form' in the page [sic]

Plus in HTML, no two elements should share the same `id` value.